# JS React - differing rotation in svg components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, rotation

Seeking advice on working with svg components and their rotation.

I have a react functional component where I can add figures, move them around the screen and rotate them.

Those figures are implemented as svgs.
Example:

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform={`rotate(${props.rotation})`}>
        <ellipse style={{ "fill": "rgb(216, 216, 216)", "stroke": "rgb(0, 0, 0)" }} cx="250" cy="250" rx="125" ry="125" />
        <text className='unselectable' style={{ "whiteSpace": "pre", "fill": "rgb(51, 51, 51)", "fontFamily": "Arial, sans-serif", "font-size": "152.2px" }} x="166.561" y="303.035" transform="matrix(0.66583, 0, 0, 0.739777, 79.047778, 60.064947)">{props.tableName}</text>
    </svg>
```

So I handle the rotation by calculating the number and applying it in the transform of the svg.
The problem is, that the text components also rotates and it becomes unreadable.

I tried to apply a negative degree to the text component but that does not work properly as the text drifts away (see screenshot).

Is there any solution to make the text not rotate while everything else in the svg rotates?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to attach this screenshot to the initial post.
If you look at the < svg > rotation variant (3rd column) - the rects/ellipse rotates as by design, but the text should not rotate with it.
[image]

Following the advice in the comments:
I put the ellipse in a < g > and gave it rotation, while the text was outside of g.

[image]

Then I put both in < g > with rotation and gave < text > neg rotation.

```
<g transform={`rotate(${props.rotation})`}>
                <ellipse style={{ "fill": "rgb(216, 216, 216)", "stroke": "rgb(0, 0, 0)" }} cx="250" cy="250" rx="125" ry="125" />

                <text className='unselectable' style={{ "whiteSpace": "pre", "fill": "rgb(51, 51, 51)", "fontFamily": "Arial, sans-serif", "font-size": "152.2px" }} x="166.561" y="303.035" transform={`matrix(0.66583, 0, 0, 0.739777, 79.047778, 60.064947) rotate(-${props.rotation})`}>{props.tableName}</text>
</g>
```

Both ellipse and text rotate at different rates and they can go outside of border.

[image]

My **main problem** (which I failed to describe) is that I need the elements (e.g. ellipse) to rotate in place (as you can see in the screenshots - inside the bordered box. But I want the text inside not to rotate with it.

Comment: put the things you want to rotate in.a <g> and rotate the <g>. Put the text outside the <g>

Comment: @RobertLongson I have tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. I'm afraid I didn't describe the problem well enough, I have made an edit to the original post.

Comment: Please improve your example code. It is unclear which elements are part of the component svg. Besides a  rotated circular ellipse is probably not a good example - since it looks the same when rotated. Quite likely you should first simplify and unravel your transformations (e.g. the text transformed via matrix).  If you only need to rotate a single element (like a rect or a n ellipse) - you don't really need a group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue, which I failed to describe (not fully understanding svgs and transform did not allow for that to happen.

The solution is close to the one proposed by @normalcepalin.

The main issue was:
I had an svg  component, containing:

```
<svg>
<lots of things>
<text>
</svg>
```

And I was applying rotation to the whole svg.
When I tried the normalcepalin method, the rotation was kind of strange and, as far as I understand now, it was so because everything in

```
<lots of things>
```

was offset from the origin point of the svg.

This offset was also the problem when trying to rotate a

```
<g>
<lots of things>
</g>
```

and not rotating the text component. Everything started rotating off the view box.

The final solution (and don't know if it's the best solution, but worked for me):

```
<svg>
  <g transform={`rotate(${props.rotation})`} style={{ "transform-origin": "50% 50%" }}>
    <lots of things>
  </g>
  <g>
    <text> </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This allows for the text to remain stationary, but for all the stuff inside the first group to rotate in it's place. The addition of transform-origin as a css parameter without a particular rotation origin coordinates allows to easily rotate the object in it's own place.

Again, I am not sure this is a best practice approach, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap what you want to rotate in a  tag like this. Then add the opposite rotation to the text

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform={`rotate(${props.rotation})`}>
    <g transform={`rotate(${-props.rotation} 250 250)`}> 
        <ellipse style={{ "fill": "rgb(216, 216, 216)", "stroke": "rgb(0, 0, 0)" }} cx="250" cy="250" rx="125" ry="125" />
        <text className='unselectable' style={{ "whiteSpace": "pre", "fill": "rgb(51, 51, 51)", "fontFamily": "Arial, sans-serif", "fontSize": "152.2px" }} x="166.561" y="303.035" transform="matrix(0.66583, 0, 0, 0.739777, 79.047778, 60.064947)">{props.tableName}</text>
    </g>
     
</svg>
```

Comment: This didn't work as well, unfortunately. I have described the issue mroe thoroughly in an edit to the original post.